# Compute Mean Residual Time For A Given Right-Censored CDF

Tags: survival

I have an analytical form CDF F(t). It is right censored as shown in the graph. I want to know how to compute mean residual time E(T-t0|T>t0) for such CDF.

[image: CDF graph]

Comment: You need to know what it would have done to the right of the censoring point had it not been censored. This information is not in your post.

Comment: It would require some sort of distributional assumption. What's not clear from your graph is what the discontinuity at t_0 with the solid point at 1 is supposed to indicate.